# minimize a sum of weighted square distances

Tags: optimization, sobolev-spaces, functional-equations, weighted-least-squares

Let $f_1, f_2$ be given polynomials of degree $k$ and we want to find a polynomial $f$ of degree $k+1$ that solves the following minimization problem on $[0,1]$:
$$f=\operatorname*{argmin}_{\hat{f}\in P_{k+1}([0,1])}w_1 \lVert \hat{f}-f_1 \rVert^2_{[0,1]}+w_2 \lVert \hat{f}-f_2 \rVert^2_{[0,1]},$$
where $w_1,w_2$ are positive constants and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{[0,1]}$ denotes $L^2$ norm over $[0,1]$.

Surely we can compute underdetermined coefficients but it would too complicated if $k$ is large. I wonder if there is any trick to quickly find the minimizer (as well as minimum if possible) without excessive computations for a general degree $k$.

Comment: I wonder if this can be done by geometry of inner product spcaes. Which inner product it is depends on the coefficients $w_1,w_2$. The mapping that takes as input the two vectors of coefficients of $f_1$ and $f_2$ and returns as output the coefficients of $\widehat f$ should be linear if I'm not mistaken, so there should be a particular matrix (depending on $w_1,w_2$) that does it. $\qquad$

Comment: Which norm do you use?

Comment: @gerw $L^2$-norm

Comment: What falls under extensive computation? It might be easier using orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: @user251257 Well, I have to calculate the coefficients for $f_1,f_2$ if using orthogonal polynomials or other basis, and in my case there are lots of $f_1,f_2$ so I want to avoid that calculation. Here $[0,1]$ is only the simplest case and it may be replaced by a two dimensional domain in my case. Simply speaking, what I expect here is to find the relation between $f$ and $f_1,f_2$ directly, without expressing them using any basis functions.

Comment: In 1D computing the coefficients is quite simple using quadrature rules (up to some reasonable $k$). Going to 2D would be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the identity:

$$
w_1||\hat{f} - f_1||_2^2 + w_2||\hat{f} - f_2||_2^2 = (w_1 + w_2)||\hat{f} - \frac{(w_1 f_1 + w_2 f_2)}{w_1 + w_2}||_2^2 + R(w_1, w_2, f_1, f_2)
$$

where $R$ does not depend on $\hat{f}$. Now you can just look for a polynomial of degree $(k+1)$ that minimizes $L2$ distance to a given polynomial of degree $k$, which you can do using standard techinques.

Edit: I just wanted to add that one can write an analogous identity for $n$ components, so it should be possible to solve analogous problem with given $f_1 , f_2 , \ldots , f_n$ and positive $w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_n$.